# Change value in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to know how I can change a value in a dictionary using list of keys and 1 value

```
my_dict = {
    'bob': {
        'name': {'first': 'FirstName', 'last': 'LastName'},
        'job': 'Developer'
    }
}

string1 = 'bob.name.first=Bob'
string1 = string.split('=')
string2 = string1[0].split('.')
string2.append(string[1])
```

Here I end up with a list of 4 items, the first 3 are keys and the last is the value.

How can I use this given list to change the value in my_dict considering that the given list keys number can be changed for example if I want to change bob.job=QA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the following function is what you are looking for, it works with any number of keys and creates intermediates dictionaries if not exist yet.

```python
d = {
    'bob': {
        'name': {
            'first': 'FirstName', 
            'last': 'LastName'
        },
        'job': 'Developer'
    }
}

def update_dict_by_expr(d, expr):
    keys_value = expr.split('=')
    keys = keys_value[0].split('.')
    value = keys_value[1]
    item = d
    while len(keys) > 1:
        key = keys.pop(0)
        if key not in item:
            item[key] = {}
        item = item[key]
    key = keys[0]
    item[key] = value

print(d)
update_dict_by_expr(d, 'bob.name.first=Bob Junior')
update_dict_by_expr(d, 'bob.name.birth.date=01/01/2017')
update_dict_by_expr(d, 'bob.name.birth.place=NYC')
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
string1 = 'bob.name.first=Bob'
string1,string2 = string1.split('=')
string1 = string1.split('.')
my_dict[string1[0]][string1[1]][string1[2]] = string2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update Bob's job you can access it using `my_dict['bob']['job']`

```
my_dict = {
    'bob': {
        'name': {'first': 'FirstName', 'last': 'LastName'},
        'job': 'Developer'
    }
}

my_dict['bob']['job'] = 'QA'

print(my_dict)
>> {'bob': {'name': {'last': 'LastName', 'first': 'FirstName'}, 'job': 'QA'}}
```

or by splitting your string:

```
my_dict = {
    'bob': {
        'name': {'first': 'FirstName', 'last': 'LastName'},
        'job': 'Developer'
    }
}

bobjob_key_value = 'bob.job=QA'
key, value = bobjob_key_value.split('=')
key = key.split('.')
my_dict[key[0]][key[1]] = value

print(my_dict)

>> {'bob': {'job': 'QA', 'name': {'last': 'LastName', 'first': 'FirstName'}}}
```

Comment: This is right but, my_dict[key[0]][key[1]] = value will break if I insert bob.name.last=LastName

Comment: So I think it should be done with a loop but I can't figure the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You want a dict with keys that can be accessed as attributes. You can achieve that by **subclassing** dict class, and add support for your need. I think this is more pythonic solution as it is much more intuative:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr] if attr in self.keys() else None

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value

my_dict = MyDict({
    'bob': MyDict(
        {'name':
         MyDict({'first': 'FirstName', 'last': 'LastName'}),
         'job':'Developer'})})

>>> my_dict.bob
{'job': 'Developer', 'name': {'last': 'LastName', 'first': 'FirstName'}}
>>> my_dict.bob.job
'Developer'
>>> my_dict.bob.name
{'last': 'LastName', 'first': 'FirstName'}
```

It does require some overhead, as you will need to build your dicts based on MyDict. Regular dicts won't work if added to this dict.

This supports setting a new value as well:

```
>>> my_dict.bob.job = 'QA'
>>> my_dict.bob.job
'QA'
```

Comment: I want to create a script which receives 2 arguments: 1: yaml file 2: value to change. It should look like myscript.py employees.yaml bob.name.first=Bob the result is the script will change the value of bob.name.first to Bob in employees.yaml. So the 2nd argument is actually a string coming from the user 'bob.name.first=bob'

Answer (score 0):

```
import yaml


def get_dictionary_replace_value(file, new_value, strip_qoutes=True):

    with open(file, 'r') as rf:
        yaml_doc = yaml.load(rf)
        rf.close()

    key, value = new_value.split('=')
    keys = key.split('.')
    inner_dict = yaml_doc

    for i in keys[:-1]:
        inner_dict = inner_dict[i]
    inner_dict[keys[-1]] = value

    with open(file, 'w') as wf:
        if strip_qoutes:
            wf.write(yaml.dump(yaml_doc, 
            default_flow_style=False).replace("'", "").replace('"', ""))
        else:
            wf.write(yaml.dump(yaml_doc, default_flow_style=False))
    wf.close()
```